# Can I have a mouse event specific to a browser window?

Tags: java, apache-flex, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, mouseevent

I am using Selenium Webdriver for Automation, and there are few flex objects which I need to interact with. I know that Webdriver could not interact with flex objects.For that I have integrate the Webdriver with the ROBOT framework.
The problem I am facing is that I need to have focus on the current window for the mouse to detect the location of an element. If I touch My mouse while the execution is in progress, the element could not be found.

Can anyone please suggest me some alternatives to trigger a mouse event explicitly for the browser window, So that I can work on other things while my test execution is in progress?

I am using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that this is possible with Robot.  However, if you use the Actions API, then you can mouse over stuff, and so forth without having the computer actually use your mouse.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(someElement);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Comment: But still after using Actions, I am unable to click the flex object.
Can you suggest me some ways I can restrict my mouse in that window?

Comment: I don't know what flex is...sorry.  Is it some sort of plugin that doesn't have WebElements?   If you aren't trying to do super-complex stuff (a single action, maybe two), then you could select the outer element around flex, and use the X/Y offset to click an individual part.